# Active record queries condition using an array and the % sign

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

[Rubyonrails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#array-conditions) suggest to avoid to use conditions as pure strings.
I am writing a simple search form for users and I am still undecided about which argument I can use to replace the question mark. Using internet documentation i tried with the following expression:

```
find_by("name LIKE ?", "%#{search}%")
```

I found, after many attempts, the following alternative best suited for my needs:

```
find_by("name = ?", "#{search}")
```

What I do not understand is the use of the double `%` in the first expression, one at the beginning of the interpolated string and the second closing it.
As far as I understood, the `LIKE` in the first expression is used to return a user based on a incomplete query, such as using `Exam` to find `Example User`. However, if I remove the double `%` it behaves like the second expression. So,  What is the double `%` useful for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have got it almost. `LIKE` is used to match any query which is like the supplied one but `%` is used to target it in a more specif way. Like if you use `LIKE exam%` then it will match anything starting with `exam` like exam, example etc. but not `preexam`. In the same way `LIKE %exam` will search for strings ending with `exam` like `preexam` but it will not match `example`.

And `LIKE %exam%` means match a string which has `exam` anywhere in string, be it at center or start or end like `example`, `preexam`, `myexamination`.

So without these `%` it just search for particular string.

Answer (score 1):

This is more a question about your database (which is not included in the question) rather than Rails, but I will draw from the Postgres documentation. Your assumption about 'like' automatically matching partial strings is incorrect.

> If pattern does not contain percent signs or underscore, then the
>   pattern only represents the string itself; in that case LIKE acts like
>   the equals operator. An underscore (_) in pattern stands for (matches)
>   any single character; a percent sign (%) matches any string of zero or
>   more characters.

Source: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/functions-matching.html

As you can see if the pattern matching contains no wildcard characters, it is the same as using an equals operator.

Final note: if you do not care about case sensitivity in your pattern matching, use `ilike` instead of `like`